# How do I pull a nested state object without it returning as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I continue to struggle with what I believe would be something simple to accomplish. The first time I tried this I used React Hooks, but this time I switched back to class based components just because I thought it would change something for some reason.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Search from './components/layout/Search'
import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    weather: {},
    loading: false
  }
  


  sendUp = async (state) => {
   this.setState({loading: true});
   const res = await axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${state}&appid={api key hidden for post.}`)
   this.setState({weather: res.data})
   this.setState({loading: false})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <Search sendUp={this.sendUp} />
        <h1>Testing this stuff {this.state.weather.coord.lat} </h1>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Hopefully my confusion makes sense. I thought it would be as simple as pulling the date like this: {this.state.weather.coord.lat}. However, I get this error. Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined. Did I just miss some sort of basic javascript fundamental or is calling nested objects different when using the React Library?

```
{
  "weather": {
    "coord": "{lat: 32.88, lon: -111.76}",
    "weather": "[{…}]",
    "base": "stations",
    "main": "{feels_like: 311.12, humidity: 32, pressure: 1012, …}",
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": "{deg: 330, speed: 3.6}",
    "clouds": "{all: 1}",
    "dt": 1595714117,
    "sys": "{country: \"US\", id: 3616, sunrise: 1595680572, suns…}",
    "timezone": -25200,
    "id": 5288636,
    "name": "Casa Grande",
    "cod": 200
  },
  "loading": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `render` function is executed at the very beginning of your component being mounted.
Everytime your state changes, the `render` function will be executed again. There are other situations where the component might render (for example, props changing).

The first time your component renders, your state is

```
state = {
    weather: {},
    loading: false
  }
```

but in your `render` function, you do

```
 <h1>Testing this stuff {this.state.weather.coord.lat} </h1>
```

This is because at this point, you haven't loaded the `weather` info yet. Your `render` component should consider that. For instance, you could do something like

```
{ this.state.weather.coord ? <h1>Testing this stuff {this.state.weather.coord.lat}</h1> : <h1>Loading weather data...</h1>}
```

That way, until your weather data is loaded, you see the text "Loading...". You could also do something more sophisticated, like showing a spinner.

Comment: Oh thanks that totally makes sense! Adding the conditional ternary will allow the info to load... does it work the same way with functional components without render function?

Comment: yes - the concept it's pretty similar. You could think that the whole Functional Component _is_ the render function by itself. Of course, that means dropping most of the events (like `componentDidUpdate`) or handling the state - but that's where the hooks come to the rescue

Answer (score 2):

Ciao, you got undefined because `this.state.weather` contains an element called `weather` so if you want to access to your object you have to write `this.state.weather.weather`. But there is another problem: if you want to get `lat` from `coord` you cannot write `this.state.weather.weather.coord.lat` because `this.state.weather.weather.coord` is a string, not a JSON object. And you cannot do neither something like `JSON.parse(this.state.weather.weather.coord)` because is not a valid JSON. So, we have to work with string and, finally, to get `lat` from `coord` you can do:

```
this.state.weather.weather.coord.split(',')[0].split(':')[1]
```